# Display element at the top inside display:flex container

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I try to display complex elements at the page, it should has image at the left top and text at the right side, I use `display:flexbox` for the parents of those elements to achive that, but images displays at the center of block [image]
I have tried to change `position` and `display` properties but it didn't change anything,  I can move it using `margin-top: -200px` but it's not a good solution.

That's how my code looks in html:

```
 <div className="company-details">
    <CompanyLogo fileName={fileName} url={url} />
    <div className="columns is-multiline">{renderFacts(facts)}</div>
  </div>
```

company-details class:

```
.company-details {
  display: flex;
}
```

The `CompanyLogo` component has:

```
.company-logo {
  width: 250px;
  margin-right: 200px;
}
```

Please help me to

Comment: try with `margin-top: auto`

Comment: Add `align-content: flex-start` to your `.company-details`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have something similar to this in your `CompanyLogo` component, a `div` inside wrapping the content.

```html
<div className="company-logo">
  <img />
</div>
```

So, if it's the case, add the following style:

```css
.company-logo {
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
.company-logo {
  align-self: flex-start;
  width: 250px;
  margin-right: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

add  "order:-1;" -> company-logo